# C++ Adding numbers continuously when input is correct or equal

Tags: c++, string, int

I want to program a Simple Quiz Program, basically, each answered correctly will add as 1 to score.

I have 2 questions with 2 answers, if the user input is the same or answer it correctly what I have to my `aEasy1` and `aEasy2` each question answered correctly will add 1 to `score`. Unfortunately, even I input both questions correct, the result I get is only 1 instead of 2.

Here are my codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int score;
  string eAnswer1, eAnswer2, aEasy1, aEasy2;

  aEasy1 = "source code";
  aEasy2 = "language translator";

  cout << "1st Question: It is a well-written set of instructions and statements to develop a program. Answer: ";
  cin.ignore();
  getline(cin, eAnswer1);
  if (eAnswer1 == aEasy1) {
    score = score + 1;
  }

  cout << "2nd Question: Source code must be translated to machine language using a? Answer: ";
  cin.ignore();
  getline(cin, eAnswer2);
  if (eAnswer2 == aEasy2) {
    score = score + 1;
  }

  cout << score << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `cin.ignore()` is doing? Hint: print both answers after they are read by your program (i.e. after `getline()`)

Comment: I think what does of `cin.ignore()` is to ignore the white space of the user's input. I just tried what you do about the hint, the 2nd answer of my 2nd question is "language translator" but when I tried to print it, it became "anguage translator"

Comment: it works now! I remove `cin.ignore()` on my 2nd question. Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't be "compiler" a sufficient answer to the 2nd question as well? ;-) (Now, probably somebody else will correct me that "interpreter" might be a reasonable alternative.)

Comment: You declare int score without assigning it a value, leading to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Add debug output statements. They'll almost certainly tell you why it's not working the way you want. Put a cout of your data before each if-statement.